# Wave equation solution of the form $u(x,t)=Ae^{i(ax-bt)}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to find or derive this particular expression of the solution to the wave equation, but I cannot and I can't even find it. Can anyone help me with a link regarding this problem? For me it has more to do with physics then math. But I feel that is a nice initial step to know how one can derive the above expression of the solution of the 1D wave equation.

Comment: The general solution to the 1D wave equation is called [d'Alembert's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula)

Comment: This is called *dispersion analysis*. Plug the proposed expression of $u$ such that $u_{tt} = -b^2 u$ and $u_{xx} = -a^2 u$ into the wave equation $u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}$. Non-trivial solutions $A \neq 0$ necessarily satisfy the dispersion relationship $b/a = \pm c$. Then, physicists usually set $a=1$ to get $u = A e^{i(x\mp ct)}$.